# Sessions in Google Analytics vs BigQuery - discrepancies

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am detecting some discrepancies between the total number of sessions in my data on Google Analytics and BigQuery. For calculating this in BQ, I use the following:

```
SELECT date, 
EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid))) 
AS sessions 
FROM [MyData]
```

The results obtained with this query are these:

> Query Results
>       Row   date    sessions
>       1 20150601    1269258
>       2 20150602    1269299
>       3 20150603    1131770

In Google Analytics, the numbers of sessions per day are:

> Day Index Sessions
>       6/1/2015  1113088
>       6/2/2015  1112203
>       6/2/2015  993178

Is there any reason for this difference?

Comment: AFAIK in analytics when you run a report it's an approximation and it's displayed on your upper left of your screen.

Comment: But I think this was supposed to be unsampled data.

Comment: @SilviaPina I'm more of a BQ/App Engine guy, but looking in the GA docs, I found this : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?rd=1#BackUpCustomReports That says your data might be sampled if you have a high volume of data. I don't know what they consider high... but 11 million sessions might hit the threshold

Comment: What numbers do you get if you do "SUM(totals.visits) as sessions" instead?

Comment: With that variant I get yet another result:

20150601 1268011  ;  20150602 1269063  ;  20150603 1131540

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following query

```
SELECT date2, 
       Count(DISTINCT sessionid) 
FROM  (SELECT Concat(clientid, "-", visitnumber, "-", date)       AS sessionId, 
              Date_trunc(Date(Parse_date('%Y%m%d', date)), month) AS date2 
       FROM   `project-id.dataset-id.ga_sessions_*` 
       WHERE  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20191201' AND '20210131' 
              AND totals.visits = 1) 
GROUP  BY date2 
ORDER  BY date2
```

The reason of discrepancy and related code are given in this article:
[Google Analytics + BigQuery Tips: Users and Sessions](https://adswerve.com/blog/google-analytics-bigquery-tips-users-sessions-part-one/)